# What is the name of this solitaire style card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

place 4 cards faced-down in one column , repeat for three, on fourth  card all facing up. the next card  place up. The card place up  say is 5 heart, then the next card for the 4 facing- card or  from deck can be any heart(same suuit) .  Another row is formed when another 5 is found , then more cards be added provided they exist in first row and match the suit? repeat until all the rows form  all the cards that belong to same suit and value is in prior row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the solitaire game [Osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis_(solitaire)) (according to the article, it is also known as "Treasure Trove").